I ran into data inconsistency in the use of mutableStateListof in Compose
Here is the minimal code to illustrate the problem:
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val items = remember { mutableStateListOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) }
    Column {
        items.forEach { item ->
            println("item: $item")
            Text(
                text = item.toString(),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectTapGestures(onTap = {
                            println("onTap: $item")
                        }, onLongPress = {
                            items.remove(item)
                        })
                    }
                    .padding(16.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

I used the onLongPress event to remove the element with value 3, and I can see that the element is correctly removed, but when I click on the element with value 4, the output of Logcat is still 3, and when I want to remove the element with value 4, the element cannot be removed.

I want the printed value to be the same as the Text displayed. How can I achieve that?

Please add the code as text. For more info, why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

@mucuute Welcome to stackvoerflow! I edited your post to include the code as text. Please directly include the code you are talking about instead of providing an image. If an answer below resolved your question, please mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer.

Please have a look at the documentation of pointerInput:
fun Modifier.pointerInput(key1: Any?, key2: Any?, block: suspend PointerInputScope.() -> Unit): Modifier

Note that you can provide a key1 and key2 parameter there.

The pointer input handling block will be cancelled and re-started when pointerInput is recomposed with a different key1 or key2.

The problem in your case is that when you remove 3, Jetpack Compose actually will not remove the third Text Composable, but instead the last one. This happens because by default, each Composable is keyed against its position in the Composable hierarchy. So what happens is

the last Text Composable is removed
the content of the Text Composables that now have a changed item are recomposed.

However, the pointerInput Modifier is not refreshed, as Jetpack Compose does not know that it depends on the value of item.
For that exact purpose, we have the key1 parameter. We can use it to tell Jetpack Compose that the pointerInput depends on the item, and then Jetpack Compose will refresh the Modifier whenever the item changes.
Please change your code to this:
Text(
    text = item.toString(),
    modifier = Modifier
        .pointerInput(item) {    // pass item as key1
            detectTapGestures(onTap = {
                println("onTap: $item")
            }, onLongPress = {
                items.remove(item)
            })
        }
        .padding(16.dp)
)

